# jump to the other direction when walljumping in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when walljumping I want the player jump to the other direction (away from the wall). Currently my wall check works fine.

I use

```
bool isCloseToWall = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, wallCheckRadius, collisionMask);
```

for the check.

So in my `Update` method I handle the inputs

```
private void SetMovement() // Input handler in Update
{
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw(StringCollection.INPUT_HORIZONTAL);

    horizontalInput *= Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? MOVEMENT_SPEED_RUN : MOVEMENT_SPEED_WALK;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (groundCheck.IsGrounded) // Default jump from the ground
        {
            groundJumpPressed = true;
        }
        else // **not** grounded
        {
            if (wallCheck.IsCloseToWall) // jump from the wall
            {
                wallJumpPressed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    movement = new Vector2(horizontalInput, rigid.velocity.y); // set this for the FixedUpdate movement
}
```

and within my `FixedUpdate` I use the `movement` Vector and go for this

```
private void Move()
{
    if (groundCheck.IsGrounded)
    {
        if (groundJumpPressed) // Default jump from the ground
        {
            movement.y = JUMP_POWER;
            groundJumpPressed = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (wallCheck.IsCloseToWall)
        {
            if (wallJumpPressed) // Walljump
            {
                // jump away from wall
                wallJumpPressed = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (movement != Vector2.zero)
    {
        rigid.velocity = movement; // move the player
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a missing part here when it comes to the `wallJumpPressed` part. I want the player jump away from the wall to the other direction.

[image: Walljump]

What do I have to pass in there? I tried

`movement.x *= -1; // change the direction`

and

`rigid.AddForce(new Vector2(-movement.x * jumpPower, jumpPower));`

but this did not work.

Comment: is that all you have tried?  just negating movement.x?  Let me ask you, if you jump, and your close to a wall and for that 1 fixed frame you negate the x, and the very next frame you reset the x... how far do you think he will travel?  especially since you are updating his velocity directly?

Comment: could you provide a little hint for me? I know this was wrong, I tried using `rigid.AddForce(new Vector2(-movement.x * jumpPower, jumpPower));` too but this did not work

Comment: I did provide a hint.  You are updating his x movement every frame, and then you are negating his x only 1 frame, a fixed update doesnt necessarily run for every update frame.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand this. I know I only call this for 1 FixedUpdate call but because of that, I tried to use `rigid.AddForce()`

Comment: AddForce will do nothing if you are overriding the rigidbody's velocity every fixedUpdate

Comment: set movement and horizontal speed in your if/else statements instead of outside the block.

Answer (score 0):

This will affect your movement while in air, but this is how I would update it:

```
private void SetMovement() // Input handler in Update
{
    // keep our y velocity on the rigidbody....
    movement.y = rigidbody.velocity.y;
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw(StringCollection.INPUT_HORIZONTAL);

    horizontalInput *= Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? MOVEMENT_SPEED_RUN : MOVEMENT_SPEED_WALK;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (groundCheck.IsGrounded) // Default jump from the ground
        {
            groundJumpPressed = true;
        }
        else // **not** grounded
        {
            if (wallCheck.IsCloseToWall) // jump from the wall
            {
                wallJumpPressed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (groundCheck.IsGrounded) // Default jump from the ground
    {
        // only instantly override x when we are on the ground.
        movement.x = horizontalInput;
    }
    else // **not** grounded
    {
        // since we are in the air, slowly lower or increase our 
        // change in direction using time.deltatime
        movement.x += horizontalInput * time.deltaTime;
        // clamp our values between our max and minimum speed.
        movement.x = Mathf.Clamp(movement.x, -MOVEMENT_SPEED_RUN, MOVEMENT_SPEED_RUN);
    }

}

private void Move()
{
    if (groundCheck.IsGrounded)
    {
        if (groundJumpPressed) // Default jump from the ground
        {
            movement.y = JUMP_POWER;
            groundJumpPressed = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (wallCheck.IsCloseToWall)
        {
            if (wallJumpPressed) // Walljump
            {
                // jump away from wall
                wallJumpPressed = false;
                // negate movement when we jump to the opposite direction
                // With changes to SetMovement, we can't just 0 out the 
                // movement.x since we are in the air.
                movement.x *= -1;  
            }
        }
    }

    if (movement != Vector2.zero)
    {
        rigid.velocity = movement; // move the player
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated to remove the issue of only getting horizontal movement while pressing jump.